# Unable to start Activity at startup of phone in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [start Activity at startup of phone in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247096/start-activity-at-startup-of-phone-in-android)

i am trying to start activity at start up of phone but whole program is not running there is a no error in program , see my coding  [Click here](http://pastebin.com/BKaE4AaU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all I hope you have made some errors when showing the code. For example I hope the file is actually called `AndroidManifest.xml` not `manifest.java`. Also I will really highly recommend you to call your classes camel-cased - such a little effort and it will make your code look better.

Now to the point - a problem I can see is that you do not declare a MAIN activity in your application like so:

```
<activity android:name=".hello">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The other thing I can suggest you is to try without the service class - this will reduce the number of steps by one and so you will have lower chance for error. I can head you up to a tutorial showing just that - starting an activity on application start going through receiver directly to activity - [see the tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/launch_activity_on_system-emulator_startup-t428.html).